# Creating a Storyboard DoubleAnimation for Width property of Rectangle using code C# UWP

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, storyboard, doubleanimation

I am testing the Storyboard.SetTarget Method. I need to animate rectangle's width and height change.
I found Microsoft example, but when I include the code in my program, the Solution does not build and deploy.

I get error like this:

> IDE0006   Error encountered while loading the project. Some project
>   features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and
>   projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
>
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I add namespace like:

```
System.Windows.Media.Animation
```

I get error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Am I using example not for UWP??

Here is the code from example that I used:

```
private void Create_And_Run_Animation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a yellow rectangle that will be the target
        // of the animation.
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.Width = 200;
        myRectangle.Height = 20;
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        myBrush.Color = myColor;
        myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

        // Add the rectangle to the tree.
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myRectangle);

        // Create a duration of 2 seconds.
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

        myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
        myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = duration;

        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, myRectangle);

        // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
        // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));

        myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
        myDoubleAnimation2.To = 40;

        // Make the Storyboard a resource.
        LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);

        // Begin the animation.
        sb.Begin();
```

Ok, I was using the example for Silverlight.

I found C# UWP sample here:

[Storyboard Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard)
and it works now, but it changes the position of rectangle and not the Width.
How can I change the transition to be applied to the Width property of Rectangle?

New code is like this:

```
    private void Create_And_Run_Animation()
    {

        // Create a red rectangle that will be the target
        // of the animation.
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.Width = 20;
        myRectangle.Height = 20;
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

        // Create the transform
        TranslateTransform stretchTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        stretchTransform.X = 0;
        stretchTransform.Y = 0;
        myRectangle.RenderTransform = stretchTransform;

        // Add the rectangle to the tree.
        InfoGrid.Children.Add(myRectangle);
        myRectangle.Name = "myWidthAnimatedRectangle";
        // Create a duration of 2 seconds.
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        myDoubleAnimation.From = 200;
        myDoubleAnimation.To = 300;
        myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
        Storyboard justintimeStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        justintimeStoryboard.Duration = duration;
        justintimeStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, stretchTransform);

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, myRectangle.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty));
        // Set the X and Y properties of the Transform to be the target properties
        // of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, "X");

        myDoubleAnimation.To = 200;


        // Make the Storyboard a resource.
        InfoGrid.Resources.Add("justintimeStoryboard", justintimeStoryboard);
        // Begin the animation.
        justintimeStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

But I cannot get the Rectangle.WidthProperty right in UWP.
Intelli says:

> cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty' to 'string'

I can't find the resources on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

> cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty' to 'string'

The problem is the `Path` parameter of `SetTargetProperty` method is string value. You could not pass `PropertyPath` to it. You just need to pass the `Width` string value.

```
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = 20;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 300;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));

Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, myRectangle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, "Width");
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, myRectangle.Name);
```

If you use the below code to animate with property, you will not see any effects. Because you have made a [dependent animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations#dependent-and-independent-animations). By default, the animation system won't run a dependent animation. You can still use this animation, but you must specifically enable each such dependent animation. To enable your animation, set the [`EnableDependentAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation) property of the animation object to true.

```
myDoubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```

For more please refer [**Storyboarded animations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations#dependent-and-independent-animations) official document.